# Can't make the AlertDialog background Transparent

Tags: android, background, transparency, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make my AlertDialog transparent because i have a backgroundimage under the alertdialog, I tried all ways on stackoverflow that is relevant with this situation but whatever i tried i couldn't.. maybe i'm missing something simple so i need help.

Here is my code

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(LoginActivity.this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null);

final AlertDialog alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
    .setView(promptsView)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) //Set to null. We override the onclick
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
    .create();

Window window = alertDialogBuilder.getWindow(); 
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

alertDialogBuilder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
// positive button and negative button controls. 
}
});

alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

Here is my xml (activity_login - promptsView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login`enter code here`"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FE9A2E" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/kadi"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/kadi"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="K.Adı :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Şifre  : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kadi"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kadi"
    android:layout_below="@+id/kadi"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/kadi"
    android:layout_width="234dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
    android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Why are you not setting transparent background to `RelativeLayout ` your Dialog's layout parent view?

Comment: if you mean this `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` , it is not working.

Comment: AlertDialog under the base or Holo theme doesn't set a window background. You will need to set up an alert dialog style that uses a transparent color for the top/bottom/etc. backgrounds. See [styles_holo.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles_holo.xml#L1144) for reference.